# Converting string to date with timezone adjustment

Tags: mysql, datetime, date-format

I am attempting to convert stirngs to dates in mysql

```
Thu Oct 23 16:46:47 2014 +02:00
```

Im unsure how to handle the +02:00, The rest is simple enough

```
 update logs
 set date = str_to_date(date_raw, '%a %b %e %T %Y')
```

This returns

```
Truncated incorrect datetime value: 'Thu Oct 23 16:46:47 2014 +02:00'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

How about a stored function?

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `ts_from_offset` $$
CREATE FUNCTION `ts_from_offset`(in_ts TINYTEXT) RETURNS datetime
NO SQL
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN

-- Thu Oct 23 16:46:47 2014 +02:00

-- this function takes an input timestamp value with an offset formatted as above,
-- and converts it to the equivalent MySQL datetime value, expressed in the current session's
-- time zone.  Since this is also the timezone that columns in the TIMESTAMP data type expect,
-- this causes the input value to be stored correctly in the native TIMESTAMP format, which is.
-- UTC under the hood.

-- if you are taking the value here and stuffing it into a non-UTC DATETIME column, you need to have 
-- session @@time_zone set to the same zone in which that column should be stored, or use
-- CONVERT(ts_from_offset('input value'),'UTC','Your Desired Time Zone');

-- http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83898/converting-string-to-date-with-timezone-adjustment/84041#84041

DECLARE offset_string TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL;
DECLARE date_string TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL;
DECLARE offset_sign TINYINT DEFAULT NULL;
DECLARE offset_hours TINYINT DEFAULT NULL;
DECLARE offset_minutes TINYINT DEFAULT NULL;

SET offset_string = SUBSTRING_INDEX(in_ts,' ',-1);

SET in_ts = LEFT(in_ts, LENGTH(in_ts) - 1 - LENGTH(offset_string));

SET offset_sign = IF(SUBSTRING(offset_string FROM 1 FOR 1) = '+', -1, +1); # we need to flip the sign, to "back out" the offset to get a time in UTC
SET offset_hours = CAST(SUBSTRING(offset_string FROM 2 FOR 2) AS SIGNED) * offset_sign;
SET offset_minutes = CAST(SUBSTRING(offset_string FROM 5 FOR 2) AS SIGNED) * offset_sign;
RETURN CONVERT_TZ(DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(in_ts,'%a %b %e %T %Y'), INTERVAL offset_hours HOUR), INTERVAL offset_minutes MINUTE),'UTC',@@time_zone);

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

---

Example output...

```
mysql> SET @@TIME_ZONE = 'UTC';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT ts_from_offset('Thu Oct 23 16:46:47 2014 +02:00');
+---------------------------------------------------+
| ts_from_offset('Thu Oct 23 16:46:47 2014 +02:00') |
+---------------------------------------------------+
| 2014-10-23 14:46:47                               |
+---------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

No warranty, but it seems like this should do the trick.

Comment: returns null only

Comment: Hmmm.  Works for me, as shown, so that would suggest that you haven't populated the MySQL time zone tables, so it's failing to do the conversion at the end.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-tzinfo-to-sql.html

Answer (score -1):

Assuming v5.6 (and I don't think this has changed), this is probably what you need to know (split up a bit, MySQL's docs tend to write HUGE blocks of text):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html

> MySQL converts TIMESTAMP values from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval. (This does not occur for other types such as DATETIME.)
>
> By default, the current time zone for each connection is the server's time. The time zone can be set on a per-connection basis.
>
> As long as the time zone setting remains constant, you get back the same value you store. If you store a TIMESTAMP value, and then change the time zone and retrieve the value, the retrieved value is different from the value you stored. This occurs because the same time zone was not used for conversion in both directions.
>
> The current time zone is available as the value of the time_zone system variable.

So, if you store a value (1023) when your session is set to UTC, and retrieve it from a session set to EST, you should get back the same value with -0500 (0523)

Comment: not sure how this is responsive to my question. i dont have a timestamp, i have a string from a log file.

Comment: You need to get the timezone of your string and either use http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz (CONVERT_TZ()) to convert your string in to whatever is the appropriate time zone for you (not forgetting that whatever you do, it gets stored as UTC), or strip off the time zone section of the string and set the session time zone to whatever is appropriate.