# Compare datetimes with dfferent timezones in MySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime, timezone

I have a field ***`opened_at`*** in MySQL table that stores datetimes in string format with different timezones:

```
2021-01-30T18:07:40+02:00
2021-01-31T01:32:40+05:00
2021-01-31T21:17:40+03:00
etc.
```

I need to `SELECT` rows from this table with values in ***`opened_at`*** within the specified local date of local timezone, for example `2021-01-31 +02:00`.
The problem is that when I cast ***`opened_at`*** to datetime I loose timezone offsets, so I can't do correct comparison. For example:

```
mysql> SELECT CAST("2021-01-30T18:07:40+02:00" AS DATETIME) = CAST("2021-01-30T18:07:40+00:00" AS DATETIME);
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| CAST("2021-01-30T18:07:40+02:00" AS DATETIME) = CAST("2021-01-30T18:07:40+00:00" AS DATETIME) |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                                             1 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

But `"2021-01-30T18:07:40+02:00"` is not equal to `"2021-01-30T18:07:40+00:00"`. There's a two-hour difference between them!

I've read [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83898/converting-string-to-date-with-timezone-adjustment), but the way in winning answer is too hard for SELECT from big number of rows.
Is there some quick and processor-efficient way to cast strings with times in different timezones for further comparison with some datetime interval?

Comment: Store all times in the same UTC tz and convert only when really needed.

Comment: @Kondybas, this is very good tactics but it's not my database and I can do nothing with it's schema, I can do only SELECT. Moreover, I simplified the task a little: in reality, the `opened_at` field is not a database field, but one of the elements of the JSON type field (\`checkbox_shifts\`.\`data\`->>'$.opened_at' AS \`opened_at\`), and this JSON absolutely cannot be changed.

Comment: It depends.  Should noon here be treated as equal to noon there?  Or how should I tell you "I will call you at noon"?  Bottom line:  You probably should have used `TIMESTAMP` instead of `DATETIME`.  (Too late now.)

Comment: @RickJames, It seems to me that storing time with a timezone other than the SQL server timezone is a bad idea anyway. But sometimes you have to start from this as a given and look for ways to do the job in such a situation.

Comment: @IvanOlshansky It's a bad idea to store time in any timezone but UTC. UTC has no daysavings transitions, no governmental intrusions etc. It's a pure time in a common reason meaning. UTC can be converted to an arbitraty TZ having proper data for conversion. And what is most valuable, UTC times/timestamps can be compared/added/substracted by plain arithmetic operations with no conversion.

Comment: @Kondybas, Yes, it can solve many problems.